# WAMPServer on 2003, 2008, 2008 R2, which OS?

Tags: operating-system, wamp, 32bit-64bit, wampserver

So we want to install WAMP Server on a Windows Server machine.  I was asked which I would want to use (Yes I have options).  I will be using WAMP for internal use only (creating and managing reports, sending emails, collecting data from website and ERP, etc..), basically its not extensively used.

So which OS would best suite my needs, does it really matter with the needs listed, 32-Bit OS or 64-Bit OS?

Various modules I would be using include CURL, SimpleXML, Node.js, MySQL, various dependencies for GIT (zlib, gettext, openssl, iconv, etc.), etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use 32-bit. Some extensions (I believe cURL is one) do not have 64-bit versions and will not work with a 64-bit WAMP.

Comment: I will add, the bit-type of the OS will not matter, just make sure you get 32-bit WAMP.